# How to remove the second from left (2) and the fifth from right (0) in the following number in R? For example:3255103161

Tags: r

How to remove the second from left (2) and the fifth from right (0) in the following number in R?   For example:3255103161.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression look behind `(?<=^\\d{1})` to match a number that has only one digit that precedes it in order to remove the two, also to match the fifth position from last, you use a look ahead `(?=.{5}$)\\d`

```
 gsub("(?<=^\\d{1})\\d|(?=.{5}$)\\d","",3255103161,perl = T)
[1] "35513161"
```

If you want it as a number you can do:

```
as.numeric(gsub("(?<=^\\d{1})\\d|(?=.{5}$)\\d","",3255103161,perl = T))
[1] 35513161
```

Also you can do:

```
a = 3255103161
pos=c(2,nchar(a)-4)
attr(pos,"match.length")=rep(1,length(pos))
regmatches(a, list(pos)) <- ""
a
[1] "35513161"
```

OR YOU CAN DO:

```
a = 3255103161
`regmatches<-`(a,list(`attr<-`(pos,"match.length",rep(1,length(pos)))),value="")
 [1] "35513161"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` to split the number into individual digits, and remove the digits as required.

```
val <- 3255103161

rmv <- c(2, nchar(val) - 4);   # Remove 2nd from left, 5th from right
paste0(unlist(strsplit(as.character(val), ""))[-rmv], collapse = "")
#[1] "35513161"
```

Convert to `integer` with

```
as.integer(paste0(unlist(strsplit(as.character(val), ""))[-rmv], collapse = ""))
#[1] 35513161
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just use `sub` to remove the 0

```
sub("0", "", 3255103161)
#[1] "325513161"
```

If it is position based

```
sub("0(.{4})$", "\\1", 3255103161)
#[1] "325513161"
```

For removing digits from both ends

```
sub("^(.).(.*)0(.{4})$", "\\1\\2\\3", 3255103161)
#[1] "35513161"
```

Comment: YES, sub(".(.{4})$", "\\1", 3255103161),  this works for "Remove the fifth from right". But how to  "Remove the second digit from left?. I still cannot figure out that.

Comment: @Ying Updated the post.  Please check